# Is it really necessary to upgrade from currently stable Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04?

Tags: upgrade

To date, my Ubuntu 22.10 looks no worse than the current interim release 23.04 and, unlike the latter, it doesn't get constant errors, for some unknown reason. And the software will end up being the same

The system just do it's job, while Lunar Lobster cannot even record a screencast normally for me, and needs constant updates.

Are all these updates to the system core and Gnome shell necessary in the end? Doesn't this make the system immediately unstable?

Comment: You chose a release of Ubuntu designed for users who want newer software and updates. Consider that your desire for fewer updates might be better met by an LTS release of Ubuntu. If a feature in 23.04 doesn't work for you, please file a bug report with enough detail for an engineer to duplicate the issue in a test environment. My own 23.04 systems seem stable and fully-functional, so your experience is not universal.

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu 23.04 is currently the *stable* release, 22.10 is now a *deprecated* & EOL, eg. check https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release and you'll note it has "*Supported: 0*" against it...  Ubuntu is a *stable release* system so my use of Ubuntu *mantic* is a *unstable* system, my current release will change to *23.10* when its deemed *stable* & it reaches RC status (*Release candidate*). Ubuntu's LTS full cycle is two years; the 24.04 cycle started the week after release of 22.04 and has 3 *stable* *interim* releases (22.10, 23.04 & 23.10) before the final LTS of 24.04 LTS.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 22.10 gets security updates until 20 July 2023 after which your system won't receive security fixes & may become a security risk any day after it.

The warning notice of the EOL is already out (*being published about six weeks prior to EOL*), one such notice being https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/14/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-20-2023/ which states

> Ubuntu announced its 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu) release almost 9 months ago, on October 20, 2022, and its support period is now nearing its end. Ubuntu 22.10 will reach end of life on July 20, 2023.

If you use your system offline, then security is less of a concern and you can ignore the EOL.

If however you use your system online (*connected to the internet*), then you're putting yourself, your data, and others around you at risk using an *unsupported* system that isn't patched for security flaws.

If you're capable of monitoring, and backporting those security patches yourself too, you could also keep using an EOL release, but that's a pretty big burden you'll be taking on.

It's not about *instability* as much as *security*.

FYI: Ubuntu 23.04 (*lunar*) has been *stable* for some time now; reaching that point when it switched from *beta* or *RC* to a released product.

Comment: Also, if you delay upgrading from 22.10 to 23.04, it will become difficult to do the upgrade later.  At least make sure you install the last set of patches for 22.10 on or shortly after July 20.   If you don't want to upgrade so often, stick with the LTS releases (22.04, 24.04) which get support for at least 5y.  Of course, if you want 24.04, you will have to wait a year (and do 3 upgrades)...